# Share post to multi friends wall using Facebook SDK and Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am want to share a post to multiple friends from website to facebook using facebook API. i have implement a code to share post on your own facebook id. but i am looking to with multiple people. Below is my code to share post on own profile.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html>


  <head>

      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



  </head>

<body>






  <!-- USE 'Asynchronous Loading' version, for IE8 to work
  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/ -->





  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <img id = "share_button" src ="img/share_button.png">





</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#share_button').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  FB.ui(
  {
  method: 'feed',
  name: 'HyperArts Blog',
  link: 'http://hyperarts.com/blog',
  picture: 'http://www.hyperarts.com/_img/TabPress-LOGO-Home.png',
  caption: 'I love HyperArts tutorials',
  description: 'The HyperArts Blog provides tutorials for all things Facebook',
  message: ''
  });
  });
  });
  </script>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        alert("afdad");
    FB.init({
      appId  : '193124077909182',
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    };

    (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
  </script>
</html>
```

you help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: side note: don´t you want to get rid of those pointless 30kb of jquery? after all, you are using it for something that is as easy in vanilla javascript (DOMContentLoaded event and click event, with addEventListener). jquery is pretty much dead, unless you really want to use some old plugin that depends on it. just my opinion though.

Answer (score 0):

Use sharer.php instead:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://hyperarts.com/blog

In that dialog, people can share to the wall of friends. It only allows one friend though. Probably to prevent users from spamming their friends.

Comment: is there any way to tag people through javascript SDK in share post

Comment: no, prefilling the message is not allowed and not possible anyway

Comment: why would you do that anyway? why would a friend want to be tagged in a shared post about your blog? tagging is for stuff where peope are actually involved.

Comment: because i making a blog which covers specific domain (area). so i want to share my post with all peoples belong to that domain from my friend list

Comment: that is not was tagging is meant for. if you want to share articles with your friends, use the sharer.php as you can see in my answer. or create a group on facebook, where you share stuff to people belonging to a specific domain/area, that would be the smarter idea.